# Accessing sub class property

Tags: c#

I need to access the property CanFly the object named `animalObj`, but I do not know how.

How can I access the property?

> [image]

I tested with `animalObj[Owl][Bird][Animal]` but with no luck.

Structure on classes:

Animal --> Bird --> Owl

Owl has the property CanFly

Comment: That screenshot doesn't help much, you should show the structure of your classes. What class has the property "CanFly"? What's its visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an instance of `Animal` which you know to be an `Owl`, and only `Owl` has the property `CanFly`, you'll have to cast the object to an `Owl` to access the property.

```
(animalObj as Owl).CanFly
```

You can check if this `Animal` really is an `Owl`, using the `is` operator:

```
if (animalObj is Owl)
{
    Owl owl = animalObj as Owl;
}
```

Furthermore, having the property `CanFly` only on `Owl` does not make much sense, unless your problem domain deals specifically with which owls can fly and which can't.

Comment: The idiomatic approach would be: `var owl = animalObj as Owl; if (owl != null) { ... }`. The `as` and `is` operators are relatively expensive compared to a comparison with `null`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Then where do you ever use an `is` operator?

Comment: @Rotem: You can use it without following cast.: `if (obj is Person) Console.WriteLine("Apply it only to Animals, not Persons!")`

Comment: You need the `is` operator when dealing with value types, as you cannot use `as` with value types (with the exclusion of `Nullable<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from that screenshot is that your `animalObj` is an instance of `Owl`, and I suppose that class inherits from `Bird`, and this one inherits from `Animal`.
`Animal` has a property called `CanFly`.

If my supposition is right, you only have to write:

```
animalObj.CanFly
```

assuming you have set `CanFly` visibility as `public`.

Comment: Owl has the property CanFly. So its on the animalObj but I don't understand how to get it. I have edited my question. You were right on the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684502/447356) is correct, it's not very elegant or flexible. I suggest adding list of abilities to the base class, and add the proper abilities in each inheriting class.

```
public enum AnimalCapability
{
    Run,
    Fly,
    Devour
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "Undefined"; } }
    protected IEnumerable<AnimalCapability> Capabilities;
    public bool HasCapability(AnimalCapability capability)
    {
        if (this.Capabilities != null)
            return this.Capabilities.ToList().Contains(capability);
        return false;
    }
}

public class Jaguar : Animal
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Jaguar"; } }
    public Jaguar()
    {
        this.Capabilities = new AnimalCapability[] { AnimalCapability.Run, AnimalCapability.Devour };
    }
}

public class Owl : Animal
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Owl"; } }
    public Owl()
    {
        this.Capabilities = new AnimalCapability[] { AnimalCapability.Fly };
    }
}
```

And using it would be as simple as this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.Add(new Jaguar());
animals.Add(new Owl());
animals.ForEach(animal =>
{
    if (animal.HasCapability(AnimalCapability.Fly))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(animal.Name + " can fly");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(animal.Name + " can't fly");
    }
});
```